# Del key does not trigger ApplicationCommands.Delete

Tags: wpf, canvas, command, ribbon, fluent

I created a custom implementation of Canvas called `DrawingCanvas`, on which the user may draw paths, rectangles, etc.

I've added support for the `ApplicationCommands.Delete` command:

```
void DrawingCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(
        ApplicationCommands.Delete,
        HandleDeleteExecuted,
        CanExecuteDelete));
}
```

and then defined a button from the Fluent Ribbon Control Suite to use it:

```
<Fluent:Button x:Name="deleteButton"
                Header="Delete"
                Icon="Images\Delete16.png"
                SizeDefinition="Middle, Small, Small"
                Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=drawingCanvas}"/>
```

Further down in the XAML a `DrawingCanvas` is defined with `x:Name="drawingCanvas"`.

When you click the button, the command is executed correctly and my handling method in `DrawingCanvas` gets called.

Now, I would expect this setup to be sufficient to trigger the command using the `Del` key, and yet, it does not.

I'm relatively new to WPF and don't know what I'm doing wrong here or at least how I can go about debugging it. Any pointer's are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you remove or comment out the Fluent:Button object, does the Del key then work?

Comment: I've removed the command from the button, but is has no effect. pressing Del does not trigger the callback. (The button is referenced several times in code, so commenting it out completely is not practical.)